# How to have Server Sent Events (SSE) working properly in Apache + Tomcat?

Tags: apache-http-server, tomcat

I'm using Apache 2.4.10 on Debian, as frontal web server, with a Tomcat 8.0.28 instance in backend.
Their purpose is to serve standard jsp pages, some of them being dynamically refreshed.

My Web Apps works fine, excepted when it comes to broadcast notifications through SSE.
After a few minutes, Tomcat goes crazy, stops serving pages (HTTP 500) and sometimes mixes SSE contents with regular HTML flow.

Important notice : in development environment, all the SSE stuff works perfectly, that is when we run Tomcat without Apache, under Windows 7 / 10.
This detail and what I read in the logs convince me that the problem lies in Apache.

Is Apache able to process SSE requests ?

If so, which configuration should I apply ?

Thanks a lot for you help.

Additional infos :

Apache's config :

```
- Apache 2.4.10 (Debian 64 bits) OpenSSL/1.0.1k
- mpm-event, with mod_headers, mod_ssl, mod_rewrite, mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http
- The Tomcat's integration is operated with the mod_proxy_ajp
```

Web apps config :

```
- Tomcat 8.0.28, with java version "1.7.0_79" (OpenJDK 64 bits)
- The connector is set to use the AJP/1.3 protocol
- SSE server based upon Jersey 2.5.1
- Tomcat hosts several Web Apps, all routed through a ProxyPass directive (such as ProxyPass /webapp1 ajp://10.10.12.2:8015/webapp1, ProxyPass /webapp2 ajp://10.10.12.2:8015/webapp2, and so on).
```

Tomcat logs :

```
[list]  07-Apr-2019 19:55:19.580 INFO [pool-13-thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.setErrorState An error occurred in processing while on a non-container thread. The connection will be closed immediately
     java.io.IOException: Relais brisé (pipe)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        [...]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
        [...]
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.action(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:410)
        [...]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.Broadcaster.broadcast(Broadcaster.java:150)
        [...]
        at SAR.DTS.Base.b.o.run(ThreadMajRappels.java:58)
        [...]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[/list]

    07-Apr-2019 20:10:05.344 INFO [ajp-nio-8015-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.checkRecycled Encountered a non-recycled response and recycled it forcedly.
     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter$RecycleRequiredException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.checkRecycled(CoyoteAdapter.java:710)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.recycle(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:943)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.release(AjpNioProtocol.java:163)
```

Apache logs :

```
[Sun Apr 07 20:05:22.338619 2019] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 6573] [client xx.xx.x.xxx:61445] AH00893: dialog to 10.10.12.2:8015 (10.10.12.2) failed, referer: http://yy.yy.yy.yyy/webapp1
    [Sun Apr 07 20:10:05.344774 2019] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 6573] [client xx.xx.x.xxx:62693] AH00992: ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed, referer: http://yy.yy.yy.yyy/webapp1
    [Sun Apr 07 20:10:05.344783 2019] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 6573] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: [client xx.xx.x.xxx:62693] AH00878: read response failed from 10.10.12.2:8015 (10.10.12.2), referer: http://yy.yy.yy.yyy/webapp1
    [Sun Apr 07 20:10:05.344745 2019] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 6573] (104)Connection reset by peer: AH01030: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
```

Comment: AJP connection timing out maybe? Can you provide your mod_proxy_ajp config?

Comment: Hi Mark, as stated above, the mod_proxy config is very basic : `ProxyPass /webapp1 ajp://10.10.12.2:8015/webapp1`. In addition, Apache is configured to only work as a reverse proxy (`ProxyRequests Off`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apache can!

I found a way to have SSE working in Apache + Tomcat by replacing the AJP connector with the very simple HTTP one:

In Apache config:

```bsh
# This statment prevents Apache from redirecting to the local URL.
# Oddly, it is unnecessary when using the AJP Connector...
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /webapp1 http://10.10.12.2:8016/webapp1
```

And in Tomcat config:

```xml
<Connector
    port="8016"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    proxyPort="80" />
```

I don't know if this is the right answer to the initial problem, but it gets me closer to the goal...

For now, I'll try 1) to find (if any) the right config for AJP and 2) to have the http config working with SSL and SSE.